# How to implement interface properties without exposing it to outside of the derived class

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, interface

Apology for this is noob question.

I'm having trouble on implementing interface properties as private. I don't want to expose it to outside of the derived class.

Maybe I'm using the interface/properties wrong. Please guide me.

I set the property as private in derived class.
I also tried to use field in interface.

Example 1: Set as private in derived class.

```
interface IHeader
{
    string title {get; set;}
}

class Head1 : IHeader
{
    private string title {get; set;}
}
```

Example 2: Set as field.

````
interface IHeader
{
    string title;
}

class Head1 : IHeader
{
    private string title;
}

```


Error message 1: '<class>' cannot implement an interface member because it is not public.

Error message 2: Interface cannot contain fields.

(Error message 2 was obvious to me).
````

Comment: why do you want to do this?  It breaks the interface if you make things private

Comment: Because I have a common properties with all the derived class. Should I declared it in the class instead?

Comment: not quite sure, before you deleted your answer you seemed kind of happy with the explicit implementation.   An explicit implmentation means if you have a "Head1" you can't get to title... but, if you cast it / use it via the interface, you can get to the title...... is that what you want?

Comment: do you want to hide property in Child class ??

Comment: use an abstract class instead of the interface. The interface is not suitable for your scenario.

Comment: @KeithNicholas, So you mean everytime I call the the Head1, I should cast it as IHeader like this : IHeader h = new Head1(); h.title = "";

Comment: @sina_Islam Oh, so this kind of design was for abstract classes?

Comment: @TimChang, yes i dont want to expose it.

Comment: Yes,I think you should consider it as abstract class.

Comment: @mjwills May I know if this design is right or wrong. Actually, I'm a beginner and still understanding OOP. I'm worrying that this design is wrong in the first place and will cause me problem in the long run. Please guide me. I'm sorry I don't have a chat privilege.

Comment: What you did in your answer is fine. Use it.

Comment: That wouldn't hide the property from outside. You can access the property from outside by casting it IHeader ((IHeader)Head1Instance).title

Answer (score 0):

If you make the interface internal and implement the interface explicitly, it will kind of hide those properties outside the assembly.

```
internal interface IHeader
{
    string title { get; set; }
}

class Head1 : IHeader
{
    string IHeader.title { get; set; }
}
```

There may be better options depending on your requirement which isn't clear. Abstract class is one option or encapsulating `Head1` in a public facing service class is another option.

Abstract class option is probably more suitable in this case.

```
abstract class HeaderAbs
{
    protected string title { get; set; }
}

class Head1 : HeaderAbs
{
    // You can access title from Head1 class but not from outside
}
```